# How to add a pulldown button in a view's toolbar?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I need to add a [pulldown button](http://www.developer.com/img/2008/03/eclipse_new_pulldown.png) to a view's toolbar in an Eclipse plugin.

Actually buttons in the toolbar are added like that :

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.viewActions">
  <viewContribution id="..." targetId="$MyViewId$">
    <action id="..."
            toolbarPath="action1"
            class="Class extending Action and implementing IViewActionDelegate">
    </action>
  </viewContribution>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've figured it out. Two ways: one using `org.eclipse.ui.viewActions` extension, the other with `org.eclipse.ui.menus`

### Using `org.eclipse.ui.viewActions` extension (eclipse >= 3.5)

- action's style must set to `pulldown`

```xml
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.viewActions">
      <viewContribution id="..." targetId="$MyViewId$">
        <action id="..."
                toolbarPath="action1"
                class="xxx.MyAction"
                style="pulldown">
        </action>
      </viewContribution>
    </extension>
```

- action class must implement `IViewActionDelegate` (required for an action contributing to a view toolbar) and `IMenuCreator` (defines the menu behavior).

```java
    public class RetrieveViolationsViewActionDelegate implements IViewActionDelegate, IMenuCreator
    {
      private IAction action;
      private Menu menu;

      // IViewActionDelegate methods
      ...

      // IMenuCreator methods
      public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection)
      {
        if (action != this.action)
        {
          action.setMenuCreator(this);
          this.action = action;
        }
      }

      public void dispose()
      {
        if (menu != null)
        {
          menu.dispose();
        }
      }

      public Menu getMenu(Control parent)
      {
        Menu menu = new Menu(parent);
        addActionToMenu(menu, new ClassImplemententingIAction());
        return menu;
      }

      public Menu getMenu(Menu parent)
      {
        // Not use
        return null;
      }



      private void addActionToMenu(Menu menu, IAction action)
      {
        ActionContributionItem item= new ActionContributionItem(action);
        item.fill(menu, -1);
      }
    }
```

### Using org.eclipse.ui.menus (eclipse >= 3.3)

- Add a new menucontribution to the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point.
- Set the location URI to `toolbar:IdOfYourView`
- Add a toolbar to this extension and a new command to this new toolbar.
- Change the command style to `pulldown`
- Create a new menucontribution and set the locationURI to `menu:IdOfThePullDownCommand`
- Add commands to this menu.

[More info](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCommands/ar01s03.html)

Comment: A good resource: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_basicext_viewActions.htm It is particularly improving this answer by specifying that MyViewId should be the Eclipse view id you wish to add a button to.