# terminate button in console of my eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have developed an eclipse plugin in xtext and I need to write some messages in console.
To do that, I have seen this site http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F and then I have implemented this code:

```
private static MessageConsole findConsole(String name) {

    if (ConsolePlugin.getDefault() == null)
        return null;
    ConsolePlugin plugin = ConsolePlugin.getDefault();
    IConsoleManager conMan = plugin.getConsoleManager();
    IConsole[] existing = conMan.getConsoles();
    for (int i = 0; i < existing.length; i++)
        if (name.equals(existing[i].getName())) {
            conMan.showConsoleView(existing[i]);
            return (MessageConsole) existing[i];
        }
    // no console found, so create a new one
    MessageConsole myConsole = new MessageConsole(name, null);
    conMan.addConsoles(new IConsole[] { myConsole });
    return myConsole;
}

public MessageConsoleStream getMessageStream() {
    MessageConsole myConsole = findConsole("console");
    if (myConsole != null) {

        IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
        IWorkbenchWindow win = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
        IWorkbenchPage page = win.getActivePage();
        String id = IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW;
        IConsoleView view;
        try {

            view = (IConsoleView) page.showView(id);
            view.display(myConsole);

            return myConsole.newMessageStream();
        } catch (PartInitException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have added org.eclipse.ui.console to plugin.xml > dependencies > required plugins.

When I want to print some message:
MessageConsoleStream out = getMessageStream();
out.println(...);

And it is working. But I need a "terminate button" in my console and it seems that this code isn't enough.
How can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That has nothing to do with the console at all. You want to create a [viewContribution](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-action-contribution/index.html#example4), which simply adds a button to the tool bar area of an existing view. There is also an [example on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773184/how-to-add-a-pulldown-button-in-a-views-toolbar). Or you might want to consult the [Eclipse help on that topic](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_basicext_viewActions.htm).