# RCP - How to add Menu Item DropDown on CoolBar

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

I want to create something like this:

[image]

I have found a tutorial here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html. It is implemented using a config.xml file and I want to know how to implement that by code.

Comment: You can find an extensive answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2788440/1774643 Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a pulldown button in a view's toolbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773184/how-to-add-a-pulldown-button-in-a-views-toolbar)